# Session data not getting destroyed from cache in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, caching

I am new to CodeIgniter. In my website I have a logout option. I have written the code to destroy the session and the logout works properly the first time in both IE and Chrome. However if I login again the logout does not work till I clear the cache and do a manual refresh. Both IE and Chrome are showing this problem. I have tried writing the cache clear method but this is also not working. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong.

my logout code

```
class logout extends CI_Controller { 

public function __construct()
{
     parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    $this->home_model->unsetsessions();
    redirect('', 'refresh');

}}
```

My Home MOdel

```
 function unsetsessions() {

    $newdata = array(
        'session_id' => '',
        'user_id' => 0,
        'user_name' => NULL,
        'user_type' => NULL
    );
    $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata);
}
```

Comment: After `$this->session->unset_userdata($newdata);` add `die(var_dump($this->session->userdata()))` and see if it is actually getting removed.

Comment: when I echo die(var_dump($this->session->userdata())) in view it shows false

Comment: Try to destroy the session after unsetting: $this->session->sess_destroy();

Comment: Can you post your login() code? Also, I usually put my login and logout methods in the same controller class...seems clunky to have separate classes for those functions when they are common to the same entity.

Comment: Wait, which cache are you clearing? Also, is this an issue with Firefox, Safari or Opera?

Comment: I am clearing the browser cache